# Data inside Flutter Provider Change Notifier is not updated

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]

he problem is that the view do not get the updated data

The process flows like this

1. Data is fetched by loadData and put it into transactionTypeList of the viewmodel
2. Print the length of the list inside the load
3. i had another function which is also called from init to print the length of the list here i get the list
4. but when i try to get the same data from the builder, the builder receives a blank

Comment: Please correct the image. It shows the viewmodel in both tab.

Answer (score 1):

Call `notifyListener()` instead of `ChangeProvider()`.
*And give more code if this doesn't solve.*

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting for your _model.loadData() method, so you can see that although it is called at the first of initState(), the print statement of loadData() is printed at last.

So, you need to await for loadData(), which you cannot do in initState(), and until the loadData() method is completed you need to show a loader in your build method.